# Problema com a instalação do pacote ReactNative-FBSDK (Autenticação via Facebook)

Tags: react-native

Estou estudando os tipo de autenticação no firebase, mas só consegui fazer funcionar a autenticação padrão (email/password); Estou com problemas para fazer a autenticação via Facebook, pois a instalação esta dando erro. 
Utilizei o comando "NPM install react-native-fbsdk" para fazer a instalação ele me retorna:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e Quando tenho fazer o link com a ferramenta usando " react-native link react-native-fbsdk" ele não reconhece o comando.

Estou iniciando no Native, então precisava saber se estou fazendo algo errado.

OBS: o comando NPM install react-native-fbsdk foi realizado dentro da pasta do projeto e após usar este comando não consigo abrir mais o projeto pelo emulador.

Comment: Poderia atualizar o titulo da sua pergunta? Desculpa, mas depois de ler nao tem nada haver com o conteudo. Voce ta dando link errado? Usa traço em vez de igual pro nome do pacote: `react-native link react-native-fbsdk`. Vale tambem notar que voce so instalou o pacote localmente como dependencia do projeto, mas nao globalmente.

Comment: @nbjhope  Quando você fala de instalar globalmente, seria instalar onde?, no C:? e depois instalar instalar no projeto?, seria isso?. 
Com relação ao link, particularmente eu não entendi como deve ser feito, e não encontrei documentação sobre, então sinceramente não sei se fiz certo ou não.
OBS: Com relação ao "traço", eu que digitei errado na hora de elaborar a pergunta.

Comment: Para instalar qualquer pacote globalmente, basta adicionar a opcao -g: `npm install -g nome-do-pacote`

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a documentação, o método de instalação do pacote é assim, dentro da pasta do novo projeto:

```
react-native install react-native-fbsdk
react-native link react-native-fbsdk
```

(Ref https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk)